# Why Fragment closes after closing FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have to do something like this

i have a fragment that reside in an activity and call  fragment activity from the fragment like

```
Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityShowGallery.class);
            in.putExtra(ActivityShowGallery.Gallery, m);
            in.putExtra(ActivityShowGallery.position, 0);
            getActivity().startActivity(in);
```

but main problem occur when i close the fragment activity then my fragment also closes automatically, i don't know why this happen???

Comment: because fragments live inside of activities. It's like if you are in a car and the car crashes .. you are informed of the crash also, through the medium of pain.

Comment: you are right, but i manually close the fragment activity on back press, i don't close the my main activity,

Comment: Do you want to start an activity from a fragment? And when you move back to your previous activity you need to view your preview activity with fragment in it?

Comment: yes that one i want,but in place of activity i open the fragment activity.] is it possible ???

Comment: Your answer is not clear. Let me assume you have activity1 with fragment1 in it. From fragment1, you need to move to activity2. When pressing back button from activity2, you need to display fragment 1 in activity1.

Comment: let it be clarify , i have 1 Activity in that 1 fragment ,and now on click open fragment Activity from fragment, and when i finish that fragment activity i want show previous fragment which is already open, that one i want. now i think it will more specific. ok

Comment: Check whether onResume is getting called in fragment or not?!!